# How to update a variable number of columns of a sqlite row in Android with edittexts

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

If I use the following code

```
public boolean updateContact(Integer id, String name, String surname, byte[] image)throws SQLiteException
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("MyName", name);
    contentValues.put("MySurname", surname);
    contentValues.put("Photo", image);
    db.update("details", contentValues, "_id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
    return true;
}
```

then If I ommit to add one column it saves null values , How I can create an update only with those fields that are not empty?

Is it possible to add

```
db.update("details", contentValues, "_id = ? OR name=? OR surname=? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any variable that is always set, like id? If so, you just have to check variables name and surname against null before adding them to contentValues:

```
if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
    contentValues.put("MyName", name);
}
```

Comment: yes there is an id , how to check the blob value which is an image the null check of image is enough? image.isEmpty() is not applicable there